# attr_accessor from ruby to php

Tags: php, ruby

I am tying to convert a ruby code into php, from scratch.
I have a few questions:

1.how would look the `attr_accessor :ID :code` in php? 
Something like this?
`private $ID=null;
private $code=null;`

2. how would look the code in php for:
   `def initialize(attributes={})
   self.ID = attributes[:ID]
   self.CODE = attributes[:code]`

Hope you can help,
Kind regards,
jhonnatan

Edited:
3. 
`def get_ID
    get('get_ID')
end`

Will it be something like this:
`public function __construct(ID)
    get('...')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP equivalent for

1 - attr_accessor :ID and `def get_ID get('get_ID') end`

```
private $ID;

public function setID($ID)
{
    $this->ID = $ID;
}

public function getID() // This is the equivalent for def get_ID get('get_ID') end
{
    return $this->ID;
}
```

2 - def initialize(attributes={})

```
public function __construct($attributes)
{
    $this->ID = $attributes['ID'];
    $this->code = $attributes['code'];

}
```

3 - def myFunction ... end

```
public function myFunction() // If it's inside a class if not remove public
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Isaac,
Thank you very much. This helps a lot.
One more question,if is not to much:)
If i have in ruby a function
`def get id
get ('....')
end`

What is the equivalent in php?:)
Thanks again

Comment: @Jhonattan Can you edit your original post with your question I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: Hi Isaac, yes, I will edit it, sorry for asking lots of questions, I'm kind of new to programming, I'm a graphic designer:).

Comment: @Jhonattan It's a pleasure to help a new progammer :)

Comment: Hi Isaac, thank you very much for the help:), yes, it's inside a class. Thanks

Comment: @Jhonattan It's the public function getID(). I put a comment next to it in my edit

Comment: @ Isaac, ohh, just seen it. Thanks again.